# Creating column index in VBA based in multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a column index in excel with this idea:

If A3 cell is between -$A$1 and $A$1 the D3 cell receives the 0 value

If A3 cell is between $A$1 and 2*$A$1 the D3 cell receives the 1 value
If A3 cell is between -2*$A$1 and -$A$1 the D3 cell receives the -1 value

If A3 cell is below -2*$A$1  the D3 cell receives the -2 value
If A3 cell is above  2*$A$1  the D3 cell receives the  2 value

Any help?

Comment: I'd start by looking at the word `IF` Also, can you post what you've tried.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have no experience in excel. I will try here and I will send you What Ive been trying.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav This is what Ive done so far: `if(-$A$1<A3<$A$1;0;if(A3>2*$A$1;2;if(A3<-2*$A$1;-2;-1)))`.

Comment: `=INT(ABS(A3)/$A$1)*IF(SIGN(A3)=SIGN($A$1),1,-1)` and if -2 and 2 are the absolute maxes then `=MIN(2,INT(ABS(A3)/$A$1))*IF(SIGN(A3)=SIGN($A$1),1,-1)`

Comment: Did you want it in VBA?

Comment: Its okay in VBA also.

Comment: I'd change your post to be excel formula rather than VBA then

Comment: @tigeravatar  If you have 1 in A1 and 3 in A3, your result is 3 using =INT(ABS(A3)/$A$1)*IF(SIGN(A3)=SIGN($A$1),1,-1)  Where it should be 2

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I added the version where it does a maximum of two.

Comment: @DiogoBastos I am unable to replicate that.  When I set A1=`1,01641404837722` and A3=`1,25521701811421` the formula gives the expected result of `1`

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks @tigeravatar

Comment: @tigeravatar sorry, my mistake.